# Background color with other size, behind background image

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` element which has a PNG image as background and behind that image a background color. The PNG image has a transparant square in the middle and round borders. I want to give the transparant square a color, but problem is that the borders also get this color. Is it possible to change the size of the color only? Or should I use a seperate div for the color and the image?

```
background-color: #6DB3F2;
background-image: url('MyImage.png');
```

Comment: Depending on your html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the size of a color. You could, however, make the corners of your PNG opaque with the color you want to have there.